# Why do Likelihood Functions sometimes have Integrals?

Tags: regression, likelihood

Suppose we have a Mixed Effects Regression Model:

$$Y = X \beta + z b + \epsilon$$

$$b \sim N(0, \Sigma_{b})$$
$$\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^{2}I)$$

$$\Sigma_{b} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma^{2}_{b1} & \sigma_{b1b2} & \ldots & \sigma_{b1bn} \\
\sigma_{b2b1} & \sigma^{2}_{b2} & \ldots & \sigma_{b2bn} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\sigma_{bnb1} & \sigma_{bnb2} & \ldots & \sigma^{2}_{bn}
\end{bmatrix}$$

From here, I can see that the marginal distribution of $Y$ should be:

$$E(Y) = X \beta$$
$$Var(Y) = Z \Sigma_{b} Z^{T} + \sigma^{2}I$$
$$f(Y|\beta, b, \sigma^{2}) \sim N(X\beta, Z\Sigma_{b}Z^{T} + \sigma^{2}I)$$

So I should be able to write the likelihood as (without any integrals):

$$l(Y|\beta, b, \sigma^{2}) = \prod N(X\beta, Z\Sigma_{b}Z^{T} + \sigma^{2}I)$$

However, using the fact that if
$f(a|b,c) \rightarrow f(a|b) = \int f(a|b,c) f(c) dc$,  I often see the likelihood written as:

$$f(Y|\beta, \sigma^{2}) = \int f(Y|b, \beta, \sigma^{2}) f(b) db$$
$$f(b) \sim N(0, \Sigma_{b})$$

Is there any reason that we introduce an integral inside the likelihood? I am guessing this is because it reduces the number of variables in the likelihood and makes estimation easier?  Its like a tradeoff - putting in the effort to perform integration simplifies the estimation down the road?

Comment: It's because $b$ is a *random effect*, not something we wish to estimate (if we did, it would be a fixed effect.)  So... we integrate it out, and write it that way to make clear that's what we're doing.  Also note that your expression $f(Y|\beta,b,\sigma^2)$ has a $b$ in it, but there is no $b$ in the r.h.s. expression, because it's been integrated out.

Comment: why dont we want to estimate the random effect? dont we need this to calculate the confidence intervals eventually?

Comment: We want to estimate the *covariance matrix* $\Sigma_b.$  The observed random effects, being realizations of random variables, are not parameters and are not estimable.

Comment: we want to estimate the values of the parameters within $\Sigma_b$ .... therefore, don't we need them?

Comment: I don't follow that.  How does $\Sigma_b$ differ from "the parameters within" it?  Both are just collections of numbers.